# PHPMailer Oddly Stops at addAddress()

Tags: php

I'm trying to use PHPmailer to email out a simple form submission (a simple 'contact us' form that would email me the information filled in the form).

I had PHPmailer working perfectly in a previous project I had so I did a copy and paste of the same code.  The problem that arises now is the php script seems to just completely halt at the addAddress code.  Everything before it runs perfectly without a hitch, but everything after that seems to just not even run.  I have this script running at the beginning of the page, so as a result, all I get is a blank page.  I've tested the above issue by putting in random echos here and there, then resubmitting my form with dummy info, and the echos were running perfectly up until the addAddress functions.

I also tried doing a try/catch function to see if there are any errors, and I get a blank page as well...not sure what's going on, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the general code I am using:

```
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = '[my email host here]';
$mail->From = 'source@email.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Contact Form';
$mail->addReplyTo('actualsource@email.com', 'Contact form');
$mail->WordWrap = 250;       // Set word wrap to 250 
$mail->isHTML(true);         // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Contact Us Website Inquiry';

$fullname = $_POST['FullName'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$message = $_POST['mess'];

$mail->Body = 'Info Request<br><br><b>Name:</b> '.$fullname.'<br><b>Phone Number:</b>'.$phone.'<br><b>Email Address:</b>'.$mail.'<br><b>Message:</b> '.$message;

//Everything after this point seems to never happen
$mail->addAddress('email1@email.com', 'John Doe1');
$mail->addAddress('email2@email.com', 'John Doe2');
$mail->addAddress('email3@email.com', 'John Doe3');

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

//Rest of the page's HTML code here.
```

Comment: AddAddress i think a is capital

Comment: It is lowercase, I checked the PHPmailer source code to make sure too. :(

Comment: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial check it here. And once test it with capital A.

Comment: I tested it with a capital A as well just in case, and still had the same problem.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Nope, that's why I'm so confused.  It's almost like it just completely stops without a warning at that line where I put the comment "//Everything after this point seems to never happen"

I have other pages on the same server that utilize PHPmailer and they work perfectly fine, so I'm pretty sure it's not a server problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reassigning mail for the post data.  You already assigned $mail for PHPMailer, which is now an object.  Got this error while testing:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class PHPMailer could not be converted to string in on line 11

Change $mail = $_POST['mail'] to something else.

Comment: Thanks so much for catching that.  I totally missed it.  That was the problem! ^^

Comment: No problem. Would you mind up voting this answer please?

Answer (score 0):

(this is not the answer)

as you are not getting anythin then use the exceptions

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);//set here true for exception handling

try {

//your entire Code STARTS
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = '[my email host here]';
$mail->From = 'source@email.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Contact Form';
$mail->addReplyTo('actualsource@email.com', 'Contact form');
$mail->WordWrap = 250;       // Set word wrap to 250 
$mail->isHTML(true);         // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Contact Us Website Inquiry';

$fullname = $_POST['FullName'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$message = $_POST['mess'];

$mail->Body = 'Info Request<br><br><b>Name:</b> '.$fullname.'<br><b>Phone Number:</b>'.$phone.'<br><b>Email Address:</b>'.$mail.'<br><b>Message:</b> '.$message;

//Everything after this point seems to never happen
$mail->addAddress('email1@email.com', 'John Doe1');
$mail->addAddress('email2@email.com', 'John Doe2');
$mail->addAddress('email3@email.com', 'John Doe3');

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

//your CODE ENDS

} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```